# Unable to connect to Android Things image on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things Image on it. I am able to see the image boot up ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGWR2.jpg)) and I can see the IP Address but I [cannot ping it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReJZy.png) from another computer on the same home network.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to do this but I realized that my Pi was being powered by the TV USB Port and I was shutting the TV off after noting down the IP Address.
Issue resolved.